# Trouble with media query and transitions

Tags: css, media-queries

My goal is when the user gets into portrait mode an image will appear for a few seconds and then turn off. 

I have tried visibility, width, height, display.It is not really a matter of setting a property as much as as it a timing thing. I can't seem to figure out how to switch a setting like visibility on going into portrait mode and then turn it off a few seconds later in pure CSS

Here are the specs

- Pure CSS
- Default so it is not showing.
- In landscape mode it will never show.
- In portrait mode it will show for a few seconds then disappear.
- The outer most container div(with 'orientation' class) will be the 
  div that gets the changes
- (optional) once it has been on and then off make it so it will never turn again.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">

  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    .orientation {
      position: absolute;
      overflow: hidden;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      min-width: 200px;
      min-height: 200px;
    }
    .orientation .outerDiv {
      position: absolute;
      overflow: hidden;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
    .orientation .innerDiv {
      position: absolute;
      overflow: hidden;
      left: 50%;
      top: 50%;
      margin-left: -100px;
      margin-top: -100px;
      background-image: url('rotate.gif');
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
    }
    @media all and (orientation: portrait) {
      .orientation {}
    }
    @media all and (orientation: landscape) {
      .orientation {}
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="orientation">
    <div class="outerDiv">
      <div class="innerDiv"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
</code>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using CSS3 animations. I made example on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/h532fxz4/ (reduce width of "result" box to make it like "portrait" view). Your code with my modifications looks now like below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">

    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        .orientation {
            position: absolute;
            overflow: hidden;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            min-width: 200px;
            min-height: 200px;
            opacity: 0;
        }

        .orientation .outerDiv {
            position: absolute;
            overflow: hidden;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }
        .orientation .innerDiv {
            position: absolute;
            overflow: hidden;
            left: 50%;
            top: 50%;
            margin-left: -100px;
            margin-top: -100px;
            background-image: url('rotate.gif');
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
        }

        @-webkit-keyframes show-out {
            0% {
                opacity: 1;
            }
            100% {
                opacity: 0;
            }
        }
        @keyframes show-out {
            0% {
                opacity: 1;
            }
            100% {
                opacity: 0;
            }
        }

        @media all and (orientation: portrait) {
            .orientation {
                opacity: 0;
                animation-name: show-out;
                animation-duration: 0.5s;
                 animation-delay: 2s;
                animation-fill-mode: backwards;
                animation-timing-function: linear;
            }
        }
        @media all and (orientation: landscape) {
            .orientation {}
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="orientation">
        <div class="outerDiv">
            <div class="innerDiv"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/21/EverestfromKalarPatarcrop.JPG" alt=""></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body> 
</html>
```

To clarify it:
 - show/hide property is "opacity" (it can be animated)
 - in media query "orientation: portrait" I added animation properties, where you can set time delay (when the effect of hiding image should start) and animation duration (how long transition should last).
 - keyframes (for webkit and other browsers), which define how opacity should change. 
 - as far as I know it is impossible to "never show img again" in pure CSS without some JavaScript code.

Comment: I tested it on iPhone 5S on chrome and safari - it works everywhere.